# Alertview in webapp - This link opens in a new window http://wwww

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I am currently developing a little webapp with iWebKit I joined a UIWebView.

And I have a little problem, I would like the external links before opening in Safari displays a alertview "*This link opens in a new window*".

AlertView With:

Title: **External Links** (No URL)
Message: **Would you open this link external mobile safari ?**
Button: **OK Cancel**

How to do that just please?

Thank you very much for your help;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the object that is designated as the UIWebViewDelegate add the following:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
     return [self verifyUserWantsToNavigateAwayFromApp];
}
```

The method that you'll have to write verifyUserWantsToNavigateAwayFromApp. Is where you should pop up the alerts and wait for the UIAlertViewDelegate to get the user's answer. Return YES to navigate, NO to cancel.